# Access 2016 - link table from Access 2019 failed: "Cannot read data in <table_name>"

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

I am developing an Access application on Access 2019. I have split my project into a frontend and backend. I am trying to deploy the application to a user that is using Access 2016. When linking the backend tables in the frontend file, I run into this error:

```
The Microsoft Access database engine cannot read the data in Receiving.
The minimum required version to read the data is 16.0.7124.1000.
```

This only happens for two of my tables however, `Customer` and `Receiving`. These are the only 2 tables to use an `AutoNumber` field with the `Field Size` set to `Long Integer`.

Is this an issue with the `AutoNumber`? Or is the `Long Integer` field size not supported in Access 2016? Wondering what the best option is for me to link this table to a 2016 version from a 2019 version.

**Edit:**

Here is the output of the *Database Documenter* tool for the `Receiving` table:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This specific error is caused by the *Large Number* data type, or BigInt.

You can read the documentation on that [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/blog/2017/03/06/new-in-access-2016-large-number-bigint-support/)

Note that support has been added to Access 2016 in later updates, that's why the minimum required version starts with *16* which corresponds to Access 2016, so just updating Access 2016 might solve your issue.

Else, remove all large number fields.

Note that *Large Number* and a number set to *Long Integer* are entirely different things, a long integer is 32-bit long and supported by all versions of Access, a *Large Number* is 64-bit long and only supported since Q2 2017, and has certain issues when working with it in VBA.

Access tends to sneak in the Large Number datatype when importing from Excel. I strongly recommend you avoid it unless you really need it, both for compatibility reasons, and to make using your tables in VBA a lot easier.

Comment: I understand how that solution would work if I was using the `Large Number` field, but I'm only using `AutoNumber` with a field size of `Long Integer`. The other fields are all set to `Short Text` so that shouldn't be a problem because I have those field types in other tables that I successfully linked.

Comment: Can you provide an exact table structure (created by the database documenter tool, for example)? Long Integer certainly is not the problem, that's what autonumbers are by default.

Comment: I added the output of the Database Documenter to the bottom of my question. Let me know if you need anything else. Thanks.

Comment: Curious. You seem to have a duplicate index, which is bad for storage and performance reasons (PrimaryKey and ID are identical indexes, one of which is clustered and the other nonclustered).  But that shouldn't really cause this issue. No Large Numbers in the related tables (Receiving Line and PO)?

Comment: Not sure how there are duplicate indexes. I've only created indexes when a PK was created, never manually. As for PO and Receiving Line Items, there are no Large Numbers. Just Number fields with `Long Integer` for the `Field Size`. I will try to update the Access version, but I'm surprised that I'm getting this error regardless of updating since I'm using something that's compatible with Access 2016.

Comment: Well, I'm very much surprised too, nothing in the database documenter seemed to indicate this would be incompatible. Try a compact & repair

Answer (score 0):

The rule tends to be simple:

You can near always go forward. That  includes word, excel, or Access.

In other words?
You have to develop with and use the lowest common version of Access. So, say you can work with Access 2010. Then 2013, 2016 and 2019 users will have no problems.

But, going "back in time" or "back in versions"?

That tends to be a problem.
So, if you still going to have some users of 2016? Then that has to be what you use for development. This issue often applies to Excel or word. You use the v-next great version and some new feature (or new format)? Then previous versions can experience trouble.